# What is the 'Adrenal Evasion' skill?

Tags: skills, rolemaster, rolemaster-fantasy-roleplaying

This skill is listed in the Rolemaster Office character builder software under the Martial Arts - Combat Maneuvers section, but I cannot find it ANYWHERE. Is it the same as Adrenal Defense (but slightly cheaper to buy for Monks/Warrior Monks)?

Answer (score 7):

### Adrenal Evasion is found in the [RMSS Martial Arts Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558063137) (1997) on pg 28 in the Skills section under the subheading 7.5 - Martial Arts.Combat Maneuvers.

This skill is from **RMSS**, which [ICE quit supporting in 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolemaster#History) in favor of the "simplified" **RMFRP**.  I am not sure why it would be in the Rolemaster Office character builder software, which is supposed to be for the **RMFRP**.

NOTE: *Adrenal Evasion* is distinguished from the similar **RMSS** skill *Adrenal Deflecting* by the fact that *Evasion* is an outright dodge of an attack, while *Adrenal Deflection* uses the body, a weapon, a shield or some other object to deflect or even catch an attack.  The similarity between the names in *Adrenal Defense* and *Adrenal Deflecting* in the old version confused out group a couple of time.  I speculate that this might have driven the name change.

In the **RMFRP** system they changed the name of *Adrenal Evasion* skills to   *Adrenal Defense*.  (*Adrenal Deflecting* still exists under the same name.) 
 This skill as described in the [School of Hard Knocks: The Skill Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558065601) (2000) on pg 24 can be used to *dodge* an attack.

**My thinking is that the developers are old school Rolemaster players, made a typo, and crossed the two systems.  You are probably OK using Adrenal Evasion as Adrenal Defense, but I would ask the developers of the character builder to be sure.**

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same as Adrenal Defense. See below (From http://skippern.github.io/iRoleMaster.help/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/skills.html)

> Adrenal Evasion
>
> Category: Martial Arts • Combat Maneuver
>
> Optional Stats Used:  Special
>
> Exhaustion Points Cost:   N/A
>
> Distance Multiplier:   N/A
>
> Occupational Skill:    N/A
>
> Lifestyle Skill:   N/A
>
> Everymans Skill:   N/A
>
> Standard Skill Default
>
> Restricted Skill   N/A
>
> From Martial Arts Companion
>
> This skill provides a bonus for evading a single attack by using a
> tumbling maneuver. To determine the effect of such an attempt, roll
> (open-ended) and add the Adrenal Evasion skill bonus. Then refer to
> the Maneuver/Movement Table. T-4.1, in the Rolemasier Standard Rules,
> using the "Hard" column against melee and thrown weapons and the
> "Extremely Hard" column versus missile weapons. If the result is a
> number, it is subtracted from the attack's roll (in addition to the
> normal DB). The skill rank (not the skill rank bonus) is added to the
> tumbler's DB for all other attacks. The Adrenal Evasion skill is
> rolled for during the round it is actively used and it requires 60%
> activity action.